# Upgrading from phonegap 2.7.0 to 2.9.0 created black border at top and bottom of iPhone 5s screen

Tags: iphone, cordova

I've been using the online phonegap build which was working fine for iOS with version 2.7.0 but since the builds for that version has stopped at phonegap.com I've had trouble upgrading to higher versions. My initial problems with deviceready not firing were fixed by a couple of lines in the config.xml, access and content lines. However now I have a working app  black border appears at the top and bottom of the screen. I've created splash page size for the iPhone 5s size but this hasn't resolved the issue. It was working fine with phonegap 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have same issue as you. Problem from splash screen in phonegap build, because phonegap build not regconize your device is iphone 5s with size 640x1136, and it will set another size(640x960 or 320x480). I had fixed by add into config.xml:

```
<gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
```